# Tkinter canvas bind on oval object is blocking class destructor

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, bind, destructor

I have a class and object `Dot` which creates a dot on a Tkinter canvas with the use of `canvas.create_oval`. After binding the dot with a button press to a function, I am not able to call the object destructor function anymore. So the line `canvas.tag_bind(self.oval, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.do_popup)` is preventing the destructor from being called, easily reproducible after comment the line out.

I tried first to first unbind the canvas `oval`, and then call the destructor, didn't matter
I tried to unbind + delete canvas object and then call the destructor, didn't matter either.
I am still relatively new to Python but I am used to program in different languages.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Dot():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
       print('test init')
       self.canvas = canvas
       self.oval = canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 200, 200, fill= 'blue')
       #canvas.tag_bind(self.oval, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.do_popup)
       canvas.tag_bind(self.oval, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.do_popup)

    def __del__(self):
        print('dot del')

    def do_popup(self, event):
        print("popup")

root=tk.Tk()
mainFr = tk.Frame(root)
mainFr.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES)
canvas = tk.Canvas(mainFr, width = 400, height = 400, bg = "white")
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES)
test = Dot(canvas)
del test
```

So removal of line 9: `canvas.tag_bind(self.oval, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.do_popup)'` the destructor works and `print('dot del')` is printed. With line 9, the destructor is not called and `print('dot del')` is not printed. Can someone please help what I am doing wrong or am I misusing the destructor?

Comment: "With line 9, the destructor is not called and 'print('test del')' is not printed."...where is test del?

Comment: The `__del__()` method in Python is **not** guaranteed to be called, unlike it is in other languages like C++. It says as much in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) if you read it closely — so counting on it running when you expect it to be or or at all is not a good programming practice. Save yourself a lot of trouble and avoid using it. If you really need whatever it does to happen, call `test.__del__()` manually.

Comment: You do `canvas.tag_bind(..., self.do_popup)` this binds `Dot.do_popup` at `canvas`. Therefore the object `test` can not deleted as long the object `canvas` exits. Try to do `canvas.unbind(...` before deleting.

Comment: Why do you care when the `Dot` is destroyed?  Shouldn’t it persist as long as the window (`root` and `canvas`) that’s displaying it exists?

Comment: Okay, thanks, than I will not use the __del__ function. I tried to unbind the tag but then still, the __del__ was not triggered.

Comment: I would like to be able to add dots and remove dots. This was the simplest piece of code which was showing that the removing dots were not working.

Comment: There's a [`Canvas.delete()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414003210id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) method that you can use to get rid of the dot. Pass it `self.oval` as an argument — i.e. `self.canvas.delete(self.oval)`.